# JPA deep inheritence annotation attributes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, inheritance, jpa, orm

I have a hierarchical JPA mapping that is several Classes deep. Something like this

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class BaseEntityClass implements Serializable {

    // lots of stuff common to all my entities.

} 

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class EntityTypeOne extends BaseEntityClass {
   // stuff common to EntityTypeOne
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class EntityTypeTwo extends BaseEntityClass {
   // stuff common to EntityTypeTwo
}
```

I know you use the @Inheritence method with the superclass to define the mapping strategy. But how does this work with deep hierarchies? I want all the leaf classes to be mapped to their own tables. Should I do SINGLE_TABLE with BaseEntityClass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base class should be marked `TABLE_PER_CLASS`. Here's an example from [OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.4/apache-openjpa-1.0.4/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_inher.html#jpa_overview_mapping_inher_tpc):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MAG")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Magazine {
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="TABLOID")
public class Tabloid
    extends Magazine {
    ...
}
```

According to the [JPA JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Inheritance.html), the `@Inheritance` annotation should be specified on the root of the class hierarchy:

> Defines the inheritance strategy to be used for an entity class
>   hierarchy. It is specified on the entity class that is the root of the
>   entity class hierarchy.

It is not specified by the specification if this annotation can be placed on a subclass and as such its behavior is undefined.

So to answer the question you have asked in the comments, if you have this hierarchy:

```
SubSub -> Sub -> Base
```

You only need to annotate `Base` with `@Inheritance(strategy = TABLE_PER_CLASS)`.

Comment: So is it the case that all superclasses in a heirarchy must have the same @Inheritence annotation? if not what would it mean to have different annotations?